# smtp server setup to send mail in send mail task ssis 2012 package

Tags: ssis

here is the error i got[Send Mail Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Failure sending mail.  System.Net.WebException: 
The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtpserver'".

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that you don't actually have an smtp server named "smtpserver".   At least not one that your SSIS server can connect to.